# How do I graph a Bayesian Network with instantiated nodes using bnlearn and graphviz?

Tags: r, bnlearn, r-graphviz

I am trying to graph a Bayesian Network (BN) with instantiated nodes using the libraries `bnlearn` and `Rgraphviz`. My workflow is as follow:

After creating a data frame with random data (the data I am actually using is obviously not random) I then discretise the data, structure learn the directed acyclic graph (DAG), fit the data to the DAG and then plot the DAG. I also plot a DAG which shows the posterior probabilities of each of the nodes.

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)

# Generating random dataframe
data_clean <- data.frame(a = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 1000),
                         b = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 1000),
                         c = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 1000),
                         d = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 1000),
                         e = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 1000))

# Discretising the data into 3 bins
bins <- 3
data_discrete <- discretize(data_clean, breaks = bins)

# Creating factors for each bin in the data
lv <- c("low", "med", "high")

for (i in names(data_discrete)){
  levels(data_discrete[, i]) = lv
}

# Structure learning the DAG from the training set
whitelist <- matrix(c("a", "b",
                      "b", "c",
                      "c", "e",
                      "a", "d",
                      "d", "e"),
                    ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))

bn.hc <- hc(data_discrete, whitelist = whitelist)

# Plotting the DAG
dag.hc <- graphviz.plot(bn.hc,
                        layout = "dot")

# Fitting the data to the structure
fitted <- bn.fit(bn.hc, data = data_discrete, method = "bayes")

# Plotting the DAG with posteriors
graphviz.chart(fitted, type = "barprob", layout = "dot")
```

The next thing I do is to manually change the distributions in the `bn.fit` object, assigned to `fitted`, and then plot a DAG that shows the instantiated nodes and the updated posterior probability of the response variable `e`.

```
# Manually instantiating
fitted_evidence <- fitted

cpt.a = matrix(c(1, 0, 0), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, lv))

cpt.c = c(1, 0, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 0, 1)
dim(cpt.c) <- c(3, 3)
dimnames(cpt.c) <-  list("c" = lv, "b" =  lv)

cpt.b = c(1, 0, 0,
          0, 1, 0,
          0, 0, 1)
dim(cpt.b) <- c(3, 3)
dimnames(cpt.b) <-  list("b" = lv, "a" =  lv)

cpt.d = c(0, 0, 1,
          0, 1, 0,
          1, 0, 0)
dim(cpt.d) <- c(3, 3)
dimnames(cpt.d) <-  list("d" = lv, "a" =  lv)

fitted_evidence$a <- cpt.a
fitted_evidence$b <- cpt.b
fitted_evidence$c <- cpt.c
fitted_evidence$d <- cpt.d

# Plotting the DAG with instantiation and posterior for response
graphviz.chart(fitted_evidence, type = "barprob", layout = "dot")
```

This is the result I get but my actual BN is much larger with many more arcs and it would be impractical to manually change the `bn.fit` object.

[image]

I would like to find out if there is a way to plot a DAG with instantiation without changing the `bn.fit` object manually? Is there a workaround or function that I am missing?

I think/hope I have read the documentation for bnlearn thoroughly. I appreciate any feedback and would be happy to change anything in the question if I have not conveyed my thoughts clearly enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `cpdist` to draw samples from the posterior given the evidence. You can then estimate the updated parameters using `bn.fit` using the `cpdist` samples. Then plot as before.

An example:

```
set.seed(69184390) # for sampling

# Your evidence vector
ev <- list(a = "low", b="low", c="low", d="high")

# draw samples
updated_dat <- cpdist(fitted, nodes=bnlearn::nodes(fitted), evidence=ev, method="lw", n=1e6)

# refit : you'll get warnings over missing levels
updated_fit <- bn.fit(bn.hc, data = updated_dat)

# plot
par(mar=rep(0,4))
graphviz.chart(updated_fit, type = "barprob", layout = "dot")
```

Note I used `bnlearn::nodes` as `nodes` is masked by a dependency of `Rgraphviz`. I tend to load `bnlearn` last.

Comment: Awesome, it works beautifully. Thank you. I will have to try it on my larger network but I don't see why it wouldn't work. You've made my day ;)